# Looking for secure video/audio/text chat solution (like BigBlueButton)

Tags: chat, red5, livechat, video-conferencing

Case: create chat room with video/audio/text support for a certain period of time. Users can join through unique URL. No need to install 3rd party software for clients (except Flash-plugins etc.).

BigBlueButton has all this but I am not sure if it's secure enough, since this is not exactly my biggest area of expertise. I couldn't get BBB to use RTMPS instead of RTMP (and do not know if it's possible) so I'm afraid that someone could capture the contents from these chats.

OpenTok looks nice but lacks text chat.

Any ideas for making BBB more secure or any other software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your level of necessary security, ie do you have compliance issues like HIPAA or PCI?

If yes,
Prepare to spend some time figuring out RTMPS implementation of OpenMeetings/BigBlueButton/etc.  There's very little good documentation out there for these specific projects with RTMPS but Red5 (the underlying software) has better documentation.

If no,
For something that allows invitations by email to restricted conference rooms check out OpenMeetings.